# how to select documents files(pdf or doc) to upload

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have an iPad app and that needs to upload resumes that may be doc file or pdf file. But I have the doubts that when I tries to upload the image a view is displayed to select the image by the help of UIImagePicker. Same as, is there any view for selecting the documents file to upload. Please help me.